# Encoding/decoding doubles with NSCoding

Tags: objective-c, ios, double, nscoding

How can I use `-[NSCoder encodeBytes:length:]` and `-[NSCoder decodeBytesWithReturnedLength:]` with a double?

I have an object conforming to `NSCoding` with two `double` properties, and am currently using `NSNumber` to encode/decode the values:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
  if (!(self = [super init]))
    return nil;

  latitude = [(NSNumber *)[decoder decodeObject] doubleValue];
  longitude = [(NSNumber *)[decoder decodeObject] doubleValue];

  return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
  [coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitude]];
  [coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitude]];
}
```

However, this is giving me unacceptable performance (6 seconds to decode with my test data, which is much smaller than the production data).

If I was using keys, I could use `-encodeDouble:forKey:`, but I'm not using keys (they're slow) and unlike on Mac OS X there is no `-encodeDouble:` method on iOS.

So, I need to use `encodeBytes:length:` and `decodeBytesWithReturnedLength:`, but my C abilities are pretty limited. I'm not exactly sure how to convert between `void *` and `double`.

Comment: Just a bit of feedback after solving this. Changing to doubles didn't create any noticeable performance improvement, but it did reduce the filesize of the archive by about 20%.

Comment: Wait, why wouldn't you just use `encodeDouble:` / `decodeDouble:`

Comment: Those two only existing Cocoa. They do not exist in UIKit. For some reason, UIKit only has `encodeDouble:forKey:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    [encoder encodeDouble:lat forKey:@"latitude"];
    [encoder encodeDouble:lng forKey:@"longitude"];

    double lat = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:@"latitude"];
    double lng = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:@"longitude"];
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed this when searching the documentation! Thanks mate, I'm changing the accepted answer to this.

Answer (score 5):

```
[coder encodeBytes:(void *)&latitude length:sizeof latitude];

NSUInteger length;
latitude = *(double *)[coder decodeBytesWithReturnedLength:&length];
```

You might be able to pass `NULL` instead of `&length`.

Comment: Thanks. By the way I tested passing NULL for `length` and it does work.

Answer (score 4):

you should just need to do something like:

```
[coder encodeBytes:(void *)&latitude length:sizeof(double)];
```

then:

```
double latitude = *(double *)([coder decodeBytesWithReturnedLength:NULL]);
```

Updated: passing NULL to decode

Comment: Since `decodeBytesWithReturnedLength:` takes an `NSUInteger*` as its argument, this won't work.

Comment: Since `decodeBytesWithReturnedLength:` returns a `void*`, you cannot dereference it without first casting it to some other type (presumably `double*`).

Comment: cheers again :) that's what i get for trying to do too many things at once

Comment: Thanks! One note: Since I'm not doing anything with `len`, I tested proving NULL and it seems to work. Maybe update your answer?